# ¿Por que este script marca que no ha sido encontrado el servicio?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Este es el script que estoy utilizando y lo unico que marca es **[o: not found**

```
#!/bin/bash
control=0
while [ $control != "1" ]; do
 clear
 service=`ps awx | grep 'isc-dhcp-server'|grep -v grep |wc -l`
 if [$service==0];then
   estado="OFF"
  else
   estado="ON"
  fi
 echo -e "PANEL DE CONTROL \n"
 echo -e "Estado ----->> $estado \n\n"
 echo "1. ON server"
 echo "2. OFF server"
 echo -e "3. Salir \n"
 case $opcion in
 1)
 service isc-dhcp-server start
  sleep 5 ;;
 2)
 service isc-dhcp-server stop
  sleep 5 ;;
 3)
  echo -e "\n"
  control=1 ;;
 esac
done
exit
```

Comment: Si enganchas el código en [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) verás el error. Se trata de la línea 6, donde tienes escrito `if [$service==0]`. Necesitas poner espacios alrededor de los `[` y `]`.

Answer (score 0):

El script tenia unos errores en el while la solucion que encontre fue la siguiente

```
#!/bin/bash

apa='apache2'
my='mysql'
dh='isc-dhcp-server'
servis=ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $apa
if [$servis>/dev/null]; then
    estado="OFF"
else
    estado="ON"
fi
serv=ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $my
if [$servis>/dev/null]; then
    estados="OFF"
else
    estados="ON"
fi
ser=ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $dh
if [$servis>/dev/null]; then
    e="OFF"
else
    e="ON"
fi
while :
do
clear
echo "Panel de control de Apache"
echo "Estado--->$estado"
echo "Panel de control de MySQL"
echo "Estado--->$estados"
echo "Panel de control de DHCP"
echo "Estado--->$e"
echo "1. ON Apache"
echo "2. OFF Apache"
echo "3. ON MySQL"
echo "4. OFF MySQL"
echo "5. ON DHCP"
echo "6. OFF DHCP"
echo "7. Activar todos"
echo "8. Salir"
read -p "Ingresa la Opcion..." opcion
case $opcion in
1)
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
estado="ON"
echo "ACTIVADO"
sleep 2;;
2)
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
estado="OFF"
echo "APAGADO"
sleep 2;;
3)
/etc/init.d/mysql start
estado="ON"
echo "ACTIVADO"
sleep 2;;
4)
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
estado="OFF"
echo "APAGADO"
sleep 2;;
5)
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
estado="ON"
echo "ACTIVADO"
sleep 2;;
6)
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server stop
estado="OFF"
echo "APAGADO"
sleep 2;;
7)
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
/etc/init.d/mysql start
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
estado="ON"
estados="ON"
e="ON"
echo "ACTIVADOS"
sleep 2;;
8)
exit;;
esac
done
```